# How do you pprint a obj.lookup() into a Tkinter textbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, tkinter, pprint

I've been trying to print the results of an ipwhois lookup into a Tkinter textbox but it's not working.

Currently i Get this error: TclError: wrong # args: should be ".40872632.46072536 insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"

Here's my code:

```
result2=unicode(set(ipList).intersection(testList));
result3=result2[:19].strip()
result4=result3[6:]
obj = ipwhois.IPWhois(result4)
results = obj.lookup()
results2= pprint.pprint(results)
text = Tkinter.Text(self)
text.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, results2)
text.insert(Tkinter.END, "")
text.pack()
text.grid(...)``
```

How do I pprint or at least split the results string by newline and why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you are trying to get the pprinted value of results2, it's returning `None` because pprint just writes the output to `sys.stdout`. When you then go on to do `text.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, None)` it throws the error that you keep receiving. This basically means you need to find another way to get the formatted string of your list - I'd recommend `"\n".join(results)`.

As a side note, unless `self` is a Tkinter.Tk() or Tkinter.Toplevel() or something of the sort, you shouldn't have it as the text widget's parent. On top of that, you can cut and shorten the code you have above to the following:

```
results2 = "\n".join(results)
text = Tkinter.Text(self)
text.insert(Tkinter.END, results2) # Write the string "results2" to the text widget
text.pack()
# text.grid(...) # Skip this, you don't need two geometry managers
```

Check [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) out to read more about Tkinter - it's a really great resource for Tcl/Tk reference.